# Reading values from mysql db to average the rows

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, json

```
-(int)getRatings:(int)idNo
{ 

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/rating-grab.php"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *json = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];



NSLog(@"json output \n:  %@  \n",json);
NSLog(@"______________\n”);

/// not sure how to access the value
NSLog(@"object at: %@\n",[json objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

----- inside php

```
// How to output values of more than one column at a time?
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(overall) FROM votes WHERE idNo=1");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
$rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

---

```
php output   [{"AVG(overall)":"5.00000”}]

Xcode output

json output 
:  (
        {
        "AVG(overall)" = "5.00000";
    }
)  
2012-04-17 15:54:12.202
```

---

I want to be able to store the average of each column as a variable.  I seem to be getting close, (surely not the most efficient way).

Comment: I can get the value by using [[json objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"AVG(overall)”];  I guess the question is... how inefficient is the way I’m doing it.  I’d like to get the average of 5 columns at once if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't modify your SQL query to get the averages of multiple columns in the same request, e.g. `SELECT AVG(overall),AVG(othercolumn1),AVG(othercolumn2),AVG(othercolumn3) FROM ...`?